# ServiceStack.OrmLite: Inserting or updating columns that are not represented in the POCO?

Tags: mysql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I looked through the docs and I didn't find anything on this subject, but I thought I'd ask, to be sure:

Is there a way for OrmLites INSERT and UPDATE APIs to make it possible in one query, to insert/update columns that are not present in the POCO?

```
DateTime myTimestamp = DateTime.Now;
db.Insert<MyPoco>(myPoco, new { MyNewColumn=myTimeStamp });
```

or something like it?

I know that I can make a custom SQL, so either make a second query, inserting the custom columns, or write the whole thing myself, but I'd like to avoid that and let OrmLite do what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) is a typed code-first ORM where each POCO is the authoritative source which maps 1:1 to their respective RDBMS tables.

You can’t use OrmLite’s typed APIs with an unknown or dynamic schema and would need to [Execute Custom SQL INSERT](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/README.md#custom-insert-and-updates), e:g:

```
db.ExecuteSql(
    "INSERT INTO page_stats (ref_id, fav_count) VALUES (@refId, @favCount)", 
     new { refId, favCount });
```